# Long messages have unnecessary horizontal scrolling on OS X

Tags: bug, chat, design

[Here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3569760#3569760), after clicking "(see full text)" there is a horizontal scrollbar displaying even tho the text is wrapped and doesn't extend past the visible box.

[image: Horizontal scrollbar is visible]

This happens both in transcript and live chat.

[image: All lines wrap]

Above is the line mentioned by the user *Dronehinge* on Safari which reportedly does not break on Windows Firefox. This also happens on Chrome and Firefox latest on OS X.

Comment: Looks like a pretty boring chatroom.

Comment: @Dronehinge But that line is wrapped, so there is no reason for a scroll bar.

Comment: @Dronehinge I am seeing every line wrapped by a JS function that re-wraps on window resize, with a lag. There are no lines that extend beyond the visible box, so he function must be inserting line breaks artificially.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior on the latest versions of Chrome and Safari on OS X.

Comment: I See the same behavior on IE , but not on firefox/windows

Comment: @Dronehinge reproduced with Chrome on Windows 7  but appears to be more a bug with the browser itself rather than bad CSS. The devs can probably find a workaround, but it's the browser's development team responsibility to fix its bugs.